# Куда сохранить данные с Json

Tags: android, sqlite

Получаю данные о фильмах с сервиса с помощью JSON. В приложении решил добавить список избранных фильмов. По сути мне нужно просто сохранить `id` фильма. Единственное что пришло на ум это создать бд. Подскажите верно ли создавать бд для всего лишь одной колонки?

Comment: можете просто в файл их записать в виде массива

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого можно использовать **SharedPreferences** - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Обычно это используют для хранения небольших данных (до 4кб) и настроек приложения. Каждая запись представляет из себя пару *ключ/значение*, но в вашем случае ключ и значение могут быть одинаковыми (главное, чтобы не было повторяющихся ID, иначе значение перезапишется).

Получите экземпляр хранилища для Вашего списка избранных фильмов:

```
SharedPreferences favoritesStorage = getSharedPreferences("favorites", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

**Добавление:**

```
favoritesStorage.edit()
                .putInt(String.valueOf(filmId), filmId)
                .apply();
```

Тут по ID фильма можете и весь JSON записать, если он не очень тяжеловесный.
Тогда получить Ваши данные вы сможете очень просто.

**Получить все записанные ID фильмов:**

```
List<Integer> films = new ArrayList<>();
for (String id : favoritesStorage.getAll().keySet()) {
    films.add(Integer.valueOf(id));
}
```

Либо получить данные о фильме по ID:

```
String json = favoritesStorage.getString(key, "");
if (!json.isEmpty()) {
    //.можете десериализовать, как вам угодно.//
}
```

Comment: Я так понимаю что гарантировать выдачу информации в последовательности в которой она была добалена данный способ не может?

Comment: Вы можете сохранять порядок, если сможете сортировать ключи.